# Query distinct not null values in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I'm just beginning to learn MongoDb and am having some problems with distinct queries.

If I for instance run the query

```
db.images.distinct('gallery')
```

I get the expected result, but also empty strings and null values. How can I write a query that just returns the values that are not null?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

to avoid only `null` values use [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/)

```
db.images.distinct( "gallery" , { "gallery" : { $ne : null } } );
```

or avoid `""`,`null` and more by specifying in an array using [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/).

```
db.images.distinct( "gallery" , { "gallery" : { $nin : ["", null] } });
```

Comment: This is nice. I tried using $exists operator, but it continued to include null values.

Comment: using $nin largely impacts the query performance.